# Awesomium C no response from awe_webview_set_callback_js_callback

Tags: javascript, html, c, user-interface, awesomium

I've asked this question on the Awesomium forms but I haven't received any response yet and figured I could speed things up by asking here too.

I am unable to reach any break point within my callback_UI() when I push the corresponding html button. The links work fine to travel between pages but the callback does not get triggered.

Here is my simple C side code:

```
#define BUFFER_LEN_CALLBACKS 100
#define NAME_UIOBJ_INDEX "object_index"
#define NAME_UICALL_INDEX "callback_index"

void callback_UI(awe_webview* view, awe_string const* object_name, awe_string const* callback_name, awe_jsarray const* args){

        char buff_object_name[BUFFER_LEN_CALLBACKS] = {0};
        char buff_callback_name[BUFFER_LEN_CALLBACKS] = {0};
        //char buff_args[BUFFER_LEN_CALLBACKS] = {0};

        // Get the strings.
        awe_string_to_utf8(object_name, buff_object_name, BUFFER_LEN_CALLBACKS);
        awe_string_to_utf8(callback_name, buff_callback_name, BUFFER_LEN_CALLBACKS);

        string s_obj_name(buff_object_name);
        string s_call_name(buff_callback_name);

        HandleCallback( s_obj_name, s_obj_name );
}

void create_uiobject(awe_webview* view, char* name){
    awe_string* awes_name = awe_string_create_from_ascii(name, sizeof(name));
    awe_webview_create_object(view, awes_name);
    awe_string_destroy(awes_name);
}

void create_uicallback(awe_webview* view,  char* name, char* callback){
    awe_string* awes_name = awe_string_create_from_ascii(name, sizeof(name));
    awe_string* awes_callback = awe_string_create_from_ascii(
        callback,sizeof(callback));
    awe_webview_set_object_callback(view, awes_name, awes_callback);
    awe_string_destroy(awes_name);
    awe_string_destroy(awes_callback);

    // Set our UI callback to let the javascript talk to our program.
    awe_webview_set_callback_js_callback(view, callback_UI);
}

void setup_javascript_objects(awe_webview* view){
    // Create our object names.
    create_uiobject(view,NAME_UIOBJ_INDEX);

    // Create our object callbacks.
    create_uicallback(view, NAME_UIOBJ_INDEX, NAME_UICALL_INDEX);
}
```

And here is my html side javascript code:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!"onclick="object_index.callback_index('hello!')" />
```

Everything else works fine. awe_webview_set_callback_js_console_message() is telling me that the "object_index" is not defined. I'm using awe_webview_create_object() to do so, but maybe I'm using it wrong. Idk.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my calls:

```
awe_string_create_from_ascii(name, sizeof(name));
```

needed to be:

```
awe_string_create_from_ascii(name, strlen(name));
```

This was a subtle but crushing error. I hope this post is able to help others who find themselves in a similar situation.